# How to average over a 2-D array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

I have a 2-D numpy array of shape `(256,128)` and I would like to average every 8 rows of the 256 together so I end up with a numpy array of shape `(32,128)` Is there any way to average just the one dimension?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can `reshape` and then average over an axis:

```
 averaged = a.reshape((32,8,128)).mean(axis=1)
```

The result is an (32,128) array.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `axis` parameter of the `np.average`. If not provide, the average of the flatten array will be calculated.

```
In [19]: a
Out[19]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4]])

In [20]: np.average(a)
Out[20]: 2.5


In [22]: np.average(a, axis=1)
Out[22]: array([ 2.,  3.])

In [23]: np.average(a, axis=0)
Out[23]: array([ 1.5,  2.5,  3.5])
```

Comment: This answers to "Is there any way to average just the one dimension?" but not to "I would like to average every 8 rows of the 256 together so I end up with a numpy array of shape (32,128)".

Answer (score 0):

using for loops

```
[m, n ] = shape(Array)
meanArray = zeros((m/8, n))

for i in range(0, m/8):
  f = i*8
  meanArray[i, :] = numpy.mean(Array[f:f+8, :], axis=1)
```